# Unable to extract the records the second time I run using the same user id

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

It only can be called once. where did I gone wrong? The second time it executes, no text appears. The Login and Site.Master are two different partial classes. I am kind of confounded on how to solve this.

Login.aspx

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     SqlDataReader dR;
    DatabaseMgmt drObj = new DatabaseMgmt();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strEmail, strPwd;
        int intShopperID;

        strEmail = txtEmail.Text.ToLower();
        strPwd = txtPwd.Text.Trim();

      string strSqlCmd = "SELECT ShopperID FROM Shopper WHERE Email ="+ "'" + strEmail + "'" + "AND Passwd ="+ "'"+ strPwd + "'";
       dR = drObj.ExecuteSelect(strSqlCmd);
        if(dR.Read())
        {
            intShopperID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ShopperID"]);
            Session["ShopperID"]=intShopperID;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            intShopperID = 0;
            lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect email or password";
            lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        dR.Close();
    }
}
```

Site.Master

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    DatabaseMgmt dBObj = new DatabaseMgmt();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["ShopperID"] != null)
        {
            string strSqlCmd;
            strSqlCmd = "SELECT Name FROM Shopper WHERE ShopperID = " + Session["ShopperID"];
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome Eric";
            logoutButton.Visible = true;
            loginButton.Visible = false;
            regButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            logoutButton.Visible = false;
            loginButton.Visible = true;
            regButton.Visible = true;
            lblWelcome.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

Display Welcome Message

First Run

[image]

Second Run

[image]

database
[image: Database]

Comment: You *really* need to learn about parametrisation; your SQL could *easily* be open to injection.

Comment: May be your session goes time out

Comment: Without more detail and more code, it is impossible to make any useful suggestions. If the query does not throw an error, then the data simply does not exist at that moment. Perhaps you connected to the wrong database or perhaps that row depends on other actions that you have not taken in your second attempt?

Comment: There was no error thrown. First round of running after registering the user. It appears but if you login in the second time. The records do not appear. I am quite confused and the parameterization is noted. This is a old project that i finally got time to fix

Comment: I still don't understand you are reading shopper id from db but not using it basically taking the existing shopperid from the session and converting to int then updating the same session variable but why? `intShopperID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ShopperID"]);
            Session["ShopperID"]=intShopperID;`

Answer (score 0):

I did not see where you are reading the `ShopperID` from the database. Perhaps that is your issue. ???

To address the Parameterisation issue, I think you should consider something more like this:

```
    public int GetShopperID(System.String strEmail, System.String strPwd) {
        int result = 0;
        string strSqlCmd = "SELECT ShopperID FROM Shopper WHERE Email = @Email AND Passwd = @Passwd";
        using (var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSqlCmd, new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_databaseConnection))) {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Passwd", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameter["@Email"].Value = strEmail;
            cmd.Parameter["@Passwd"].Value = strPwd;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (reader.Read()) {
                    result = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ShopperID"]);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Erm small problem, they belong in two separate partial classes and aspx

Comment: @DulioGesualdo, the database class should be separate from the classes anyway. You can still pass the `String strEmail` and `String strPwd` into a different class. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears you close your connection, however you don't have an explicit open connection (unless you didn't include that line by mistake) which on a postback your query won't produce results since the connection is closed after you run it the first time. Second, confirm you don't have your code in a !Page.IsPostBack, which could also cause it not to appear. Finally you can do all that you are trying to do using one datareader instead of opening up two datareaders with this:

```
string strEmail = txtEmail.Text.ToLower();
            string strPwd = txtPwd.Text.Trim();
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ShopperID, Name FROM Shopper WHERE Email = @Email AND Passwrd = @Passwrd", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", strEmail);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", strPwd);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            if(dr["ShopperID"].ToString() != Session["ShopperID"].ToString())
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
                            }
                            else if (dr["ShopperID"].ToString() == Session["ShopperID"].ToString())
                            {
                                lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + dr["Name"].ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect email or password";
                                lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

This also addresses the SQL injection by using Type-Safe SQL Parameters, which was outlined as an issue in other comments.

Comment: Erm small problem, they belong in two separate partial classes and aspx